# $ \int_0^\infty \ \frac{(x\cdot\cos x - \sin x)^3}{x^6} \ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

> What is the value of
>
> $$
> \int_0^\infty \ \frac{(x\cdot\cos x - \sin x)^3}{x^6} \ dx
> $$

I have no idea how to start with this integral, any hint?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+(x*cosx-sinx)%5E3%2F(x%5E6)

Comment: Try something along the lines of $$\frac{(x\cos x-\sin x)^3}{x^6} = \left(\frac{x\cos x - \sin x}{x^2}\right)^3 = \left(\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^3.$$I'm leaving this as a comment because I couldn't go further. Maybe you can.

Comment: Could be useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral

Answer (score 4):

You may use the Laplace transform:
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x^6}\right)=\frac{s^5}{120},\qquad \mathcal{L}\left((x\cos x-\sin x)^3\right) = \frac{31104-196992 s^2-94080 s^4-13440 s^6}{(s^2+1)^4(s^2+9)^4}$$
turning the original integral into
$$ \frac{1}{120}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{31104s^5-196992 s^7-94080 s^9-13440 s^{11}}{(s^2+1)^4(s^2+9)^4}\,ds $$
that by partial fraction decomposition equals:

> $$\color{red}{\frac{4-9\log 3}{40}}$$

Comment: Does Wolfram Alpha not know Laplace transforms?  I'm a little surprised Wolfram didn't get it.

Comment: @alphacapture: probably it is just a computation time issue. I just checked the above lines and the final outcome with my (old) version of Mathematica and it is fine with them.